# Query regarding if else

Tags: shell

am very new to unix/linux. I am writing a shell script to check a filename and rename it if it matches a certain name. However, I am getting the error command not found on my if statement. Can someone help to identify what the error is,

```
if [[ $Curr_Actual_File_Name == filename_*.csv ]];
            then
            s=`echo $Curr_Actual_File_Name | cut -c 33-46`
            Curr_Actual_File_Name_1 = filename_fmchanged_$s.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic error is that you have a space after `Curr_Actual_File_Name_1` which turns it into a command.  Make it `Curr_Actual_File_Name_1=filename_fmchanged_$s.csv`, or `Curr_Actual_File_Name_1="filename_fmchanged_$s.csv"`

Comment: Thank you i will make that change. But as of now, its not going into if, as am getting error at the line where the if statement is.

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to put `$Curr_Actual_File_Name` in quotes like `"$Curr_Actual_File_Name"` in case it is empty or contains a space.  It would be helpful if you shared a complete script (also indicate which shell you are using - bash, tcsh, etc.) where you set the variable manually to some example.  That way we can run it and look.  The fragment above doesn't have a `fi` to close the `if`, for example.

Comment: a=test1.txt
b=test2.txt
if [[$a==$b]];
then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
-bash: [[test1.txt==test1.txt]]: command not found
is this is bit more helpful? while i get this error on the if statement, i get the result as false which is the else condition.

Comment: @phoedrace Regarding your last comment here, there needs to be a space after `[[` and before `]]`. This was not an issue in the code in the actual question.

Comment: @tetech, it's not strictly necessary to quote the variable on the left-hand side of `==` within `[[...]]`, but it is good practice.

Comment: @glenn jackman I agree, I said that it is a good idea, not that it is necessary.